# How true is this slide on deep learning claiming that all improvements from 1980s are only due to much more data and much faster computers?

Tags: deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I was listening to a talk and saw this slide:

[image]

How true is it?

Comment: I need more context.

Comment: it would help if you cited the researcher. to me, at its core deep learning involves much larger networks in neuron counts and more layers. admittedly that is somewhat implied by the above points which seem roughly accurate. the above points _facilitate_ larger networks.

Comment: What is the source for this?

Answer (score 12):

I was browsing the [AI StackExchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) and ran across a very similar question: [What distinguishes “Deep Learning” from other neural networks?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-distinguishes-deep-learning-from-other-neural-networks)

Since the AI StackExchange will close tomorrow (again), I'll copy the two top answers here (user  contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required):

---

Author: [mommi84less](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/22/mommi84)

> Two well-cited 2006 papers brought the research interest back to deep
>   learning. In [*"A fast learning algorithm for deep belief
>   nets"*](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/fastnc.pdf), the
>   authors define a deep belief net as:
>
> > [...] densely-connected belief nets that have many hidden layers.
>
> We find almost the same description for deep networks in ["*Greedy
>   Layer-Wise Training of Deep
>   Networks"*](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2006_739.pdf):
>
> > Deep multi-layer neural networks have many levels of non-linearities [...]
>
> Then, in the survey paper [*"Representation Learning: A Review and New
>   Perspectives"*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5538.pdf), deep learning is
>   used to encompass all techniques (see also [this talk](http://videolectures.net/okt09_bengio_ldhr/)) and is
>   defined as:
>
> > [...] constructing multiple levels of representation or learning a hierarchy of features.
>
> The adjective "deep" was thus used by the authors above to highlight
>   the **use of multiple non-linear hidden layers**.

---

Author: [lejlot](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/50/lejlot)

> Just to add to @mommi84 answer.
>
> Deep learning is **not limited** to neural networks. This is more
>   broad concept than just Hinton's DBNs etc. Deep learning is about the
>
> > > constructing multiple levels of representation or learning a hierarchy of features.
>
> So it is a name for **hierarchical representation learning**
>   algorithms. There are deep models based on Hidden Markov Models,
>   Conditional Random Fields, Support Vector Machines etc. The only
>   common thing is, that instead of (popular in '90s) **feature
>   engineering**, where researchers were trying to create set of
>   features, which is the best for solving some classification problem -
>   these machines can work out **their own representation** from **raw
>   data**. In particular - applied to image recognition (raw images) they
>   produce multi level representation consisting of pixels, then lines,
>   then face features (if we are working with faces) like noses, eyes,
>   and finally - generalized faces. If applied to Natural Language
>   Processing - they construct language model, which connects words into
>   chunks, chunks into sentences etc.

---

Another interesting slide:

[image]

[source](https://twitter.com/shivon/status/864889085697024000)

Answer (score 7):

Dropout, from Hinton in 2006, is said to be the greatest improvement in deep learning of the last 10 years, because it reduces a lot overfitting.

Comment: 2006? As far as I know, it was introduced in 2014 in http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf.

Answer (score 6):

This is certainly a question that will provoke controversy.

When neural networks are used in deep learning they are typically trained in ways that weren't used in the 1980's.  In particular strategies that pretrain individual layers of the neural network to recognize features at different level are claimed to make it easier to train networks with several layers.  That's certainly a new development since the 1980's.

Answer (score 5):

The key is the word "deep" in deep learning. Someone (forgot ref) in the 80s proved that all non-linear functions could be approximated by a *single* layer neural network with, of course, a sufficiently large number of hidden units. I think this result probably discouraged people from seeking deeper network in the earlier era.

But depth of the network is what proved to be the crucial element in hierarchical representation that drives the success of many of today's applications.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, the ANN starts in the 50s. Check out one of ML rock stars Yann LeCun's slides for an authentic and comprehensive intro. 
http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~yann/talks/lecun-ranzato-icml2013.pdf

Comment: This is to short for an answer by our standards, more of a comment.  You should really expand it into a full answer by giving some of the important points from that slide!