# "Data beats hardware and algorithms in neural nets" paper?

Tags: machine-learning, references, large-data

I'm trying to track down the citation information for an article.  The paper concerned itself with the recent explosion in successful applications of neural networks, and whether this was cause by more data, better algorithms, or faster hardware.  It provided a number of detailed examples (e.g., data corpora with some well-defined performance metric, like MNIST or ImageNet).  The conclusion was that the primary driving force was availability of data.

I think I read the paper in 2014, probably in arXiv, but I have now spent many hours searching and cannot find it.  If anyone can point me to this paper, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I edited this question to be clear that merely a citation is sought, not potentially pirated materials. https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5196/links-to-copyright-material?cb=1

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you for clarifying.  In any event, I think the original paper was freely available.

Comment: [How true is this slide on deep learning claiming that all improvements from 1980s are only due to much more data and much faster computers?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/86800/12359)

Comment: @Sycorax Universities spend billions each year to pay to access research papers. Paywalls slow down research. I don't think we should be so proactive to defend the academic publishing industry. [Reference for annual journal subscription costs paid per university?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29923/452); [Are there any known Universities that refuse to pay for paywall access to academic journals?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/71970/452); [What are the profit margins of academic publishers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/31605/452)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You've raised a meta.SE issue. You should post your opinion there.

Comment: @Sycorax sure did [Links to copyright material](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5203/12359)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I made the edit because a citation is a complete answer to OP’s question, but a document may be judged to be piracy (correctly or incorrectly). The edit seemed like the best way to help OP get an answer, without risking an argument over copyright.